# Retrieve object by id from database of Firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am writing an Android app and I am trying to retrieve an object of the class "User.java" by ID from its Firebase pertinent table.
I can't find what I am doing wrong; can someone help me with this? I'll be very grateful. Thanks.

This is the error I am getting:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Double to type com.example.nidailyas.fitme.User
```

My code:

```
 DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 mDatabase.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot userDetails : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                User user = userDetails.getValue(User.class);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

User.java

```
import java.util.Date;
public class User {
String userId; //PK
String name;
Date dateOfBirth;
String gender;
double weight;
double height;
double begin_bp_upper;
double getBegin_bp_lower;
int score;
String planningId; //FK
String levelId; //FK
String profileImageUrl;
public User() {
}
public User(String userId, String name, Date dateOfBirth, String gender, double weight, double height, double begin_bp_upper, double getBegin_bp_lower, int score, String planningId, String levelId, String profileImageUrl) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
    this.begin_bp_upper = begin_bp_upper;
    this.getBegin_bp_lower = getBegin_bp_lower;
    this.score = score;
    this.planningId = planningId;
    this.levelId = levelId;
    this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
}

public String getProfileImageUrl() {
    return profileImageUrl;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public String getPlanningId() {
    return planningId;
}

public String getLevelId() {
    return levelId;
}

public double getBegin_bp_upper() {
    return begin_bp_upper;
}

public double getGetBegin_bp_lower() {
    return getBegin_bp_lower;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}
}
```

[Firebase db looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAUsV.png)

Comment: Firebase doesn't recognize `Date`, you need to use a string

Comment: @Chisko I have changed the type of date to String, but it still doesn't work. And throws same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the database reference:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
```

You're calling for `users/{userId}` value which should return a single user object from the database.
*(This is true considering how you design your data schema)*

The `onDataChange` argument `dataSnapshot` is returning the user object, so, when you're calling `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` your asking for the children of the user object, in this particular case, that turns to be the properties of the user (begin_bp_upper, dateOfBirth, gender, ....).

Making a wild guess, i assume the exception thrown is because `User user = userDetails.getValue(User.class);` is trying to convert the value of `begin_bp_upper` (which is a Double) to type `User`.

So, instead of using that `for` statement, consider `dataSnapshot` as the user object:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
         }
}
```